# By second packet count / traffic on a port

Tags: linux, networking

I'd like something similar to `nload`, but I want the (second by second) packet count / traffic total on a port rather than a network card.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) .

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic
> down per protocol or per subnet, like most tools do, it groups
> bandwidth by process.

Meaning you would know the process which has a port listening and go from there.